# Crystal Reports Same field twice with Different Criteria(Parameters)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to create a report where i could compare the **same field** using two **different Date Ranges**. The field data will be an addition of the data in this Range. I have created the field twice and set up four Date Input Parameters for the Date Ranges. I tried `If .. Then ..` and `While .. Do ..` operators but did not seem to work. Is there any other way?

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------

Data:

```
 1/1/2015 15 20 
 2/1/2015 20 25
 1/2/2015 25 30
 2/2/2015 30 35
```

Ranges from parameters

Range1 for field1 : 1/1/2015 - 1/2/2015

Range2 for field2 : 1/2/2015 - 1/3/2015

Expecting Data Field 1 : 35(15+20) , 45(20+25) Field 2 : 55(25+30) , 65(30+35)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, Where do want to check your criteria? and for checking multiple criterias you can use `AND` operator ;).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i used the `and` operator. I want to filter in a way the data in order to get the data for the first range in the one field and for the second range in the other field. Is this possible?

Comment: Why dont you just group by date??

Comment: Well, that would be a solution but i need the data aligned so i could compare the change between the two dates.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i have found for this problem is to create a subreport similar to the main report and by linking the parameters of the second date range with the subreport i will get the correct data. For example,

1. In the main report Report>Selection Expert>set the first date range for the report `field date>=from date AND field date<=to date`.
2. After making the related links of the second range date parameters with the subreport, edit the subreport (same parameters should be included in the subreport)
3. Apply the same formula mentioned above with the new parameters as criteria.

Then run the report :)